# Difference between $db->query($query) and $result->num_rows

Tags: php, object, mysqli

I am new to object oriented php. I understand what this line means

```
$result = $db->query($query);
```

here $db is the object referring to an instance of class mysqli. Right?

But I do not understand

```
$total_num_rows = $result->num_rows;
```

and

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
```

I know what they do. But can't wrap my head around why its written with $result->...

The entire script :

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "compdb";

@ $db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("Connection could not be established");
}

$query = "SELECT company_id FROM company_basic_details WHERE company_name = 'ABC'";
$result = $db->query($query);

$total_num_rows = $result->num_rows;

echo "The Results Are : <br>";

while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
    echo $row['company_id'];
}
```

?>

Comment: You more familiar with say calling a function and passing in $result to it?  This is just what OOP is.  You perform these methods against the objects.  Result is a result-set, it can be iterated, it can tell you the row count.  Will help to be very familiar with the [interface of mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php).

Comment: @ficuscr what is $result here? is it an array? or can it be called an object?

Comment: @StacyJ It's an object. The `query` method on the `$db` instance returns an object as its response

Comment: `var_dump` it and you tell you me :) It is in fact an object.  One of these.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php - Again, look at the class docs I linked.  Shows clearly what object is returned and then in turn what methods are available for said object.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are new to *OOP* (object oriented programming), I will try to walk you through as best as I can.

When you get `$db` that is a connection object you have gotten, and you can use that to call instance methods.

The expression `$result = $db->query($query)` refers to calling the query method using the `$db` object and then passing in the `$query` that was created above. So the `-> operator` represents an object calling a method in this case.

This statement now creates a `$result` object which is used in `$total_num_rows = $result->num_rows;`. This line uses the `$result` object and gets the number of rows and stores it in the variable `$total_num_rows`. Which is like getting the length of an array if you are used to arrays.

On the line you talked about, `$row = $result->fetch_array()`, the `$result` object is used to call the `fetch_array()`method which returns a single row of data as an array and you store that in `$row`.

Answer (score 0):

The query from $db is passing back an instance of a mysqli_result object containing your results, which is why you're using the method from $result, rather than $db. Your $db instance is just containing your request.

You can look here to better understand what's being passed back. http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Answer (score 0):

When you do a query you will get a new object as a response (instance of Mysqli_Result) assuming there are no query errors which will return false instead.

This new object represents the result of your query. But not the database connection itself. It has a property `$result->num_rows` to get the number of rows in the result set. `$result->fetch_array()` will return a new row (as an array) each time its called (Uses an internal pointer).

Comment: Just edited to clarify a little since the OP seemed slightly confused between whether it was an array or object